# ReFS can't be mounted any more

Tags: windows-server-2016, mount, refs

On a Windows Server 2016 the ReFS volume can't be mounted any more. The eventlog shows

**refs 133**

> The file system detected a checksum error and was not able to correct it.  The name of the file or folder is ....

**refs 135**

> Volume is formatted as ReFS but ReFS is unable to mount it; ReFS encountered status The volume repair was not successful.

`Diskpart` shows an emtpy, raw formatted 50TB disk.

All suggestion I found were to unmount / mount the disk (which didn't help) or to use a data recovery software.

The underlying hardware raid seems to work properly.

Has anybody faced this errors and solved it?

Comment: This might be late.. did you perhaps "break" the ReFS version by mounting the drive on a Windows Server 2019? (I don't know a fix, I think I just had that issue with WS2019/WS2022, also in a backup scenario.)

Comment: @AndreasReiff, thanks for your comment. No, we just rebooted the system.

Comment: Well that sounds like a super easy solution. :) Glad it worked out for you.

Comment: @AndreasReiff, :-) no, this was not the solution - the error happened after the reboot. This was the backup server and we lost 2 years of backups.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to restore ReFS one time by using free software which is simply restoring the partition if no blocks were written. However, it can be a rare situation where nothing can help restoring ReFS partition cause metadata just corrupted or missed and nothing will help...

Do you have any backups?

What is your reason to use ReFS instead of NTFS

Comment: This is the backupserver. We use ReFS due to the veeam integration in ReFS. Yes, we have offsite backups but would loose the backups older than 4 weeks.

Comment: Can you recommend me any recovery solution?

Comment: @marsh-wiggle If you really need to use ReFS for backup repo you'd better stick with Windows Server 2016 as it has ReFS more or less working. Windows Server 2019 should be avoided according to Veeam B&R PM guy. https://www.reddit.com/r/Veeam/comments/bc5qen/is_it_possible_to_for_a_br_server_to_process/